# Data-first Azure deployment using Entity Framework database issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in the process of deploying my web-app to Azure using data-first Entity framework. I have published my site, but when the page loads, my UI framework appears with the text:

[image]

Which leads me to believe that my database was not deployed correctly. Here's the process I took:

1. Created App Service.
2. Explore additional Azure Services
3. Add SQL Database -> Admin username: adminuser1, admin pass: adminpass1, **Connection String Name:** UnearthEntities (username and pass are temp for stackoverflow post)
4. Create and Publish

This gets me to that screenshot above.

5. When I go to the publish page, under the summary tab I click settings and under that settings tab there I see my three databases:

   ApplicationDbContext (DefaultConnection), SongModelDbContext, and UnearthEntities.
6. All of their remote connection string inputs were blank so I went to my web.config and found my connectionStrings, I removed my ip and username and pass just incase it was necessary for stack overflow security

Here's my Unearth Entities Connection string

```
    <add name="UnearthEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.UnearthEntities.csdl|res://*/Data.UnearthEntities.ssdl|res://*/Data.UnearthEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;initial catalog=marsman57_;integrated security=False;user id=stackoverflowid1;password=stackoverflowpasswd1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I added the UnearthEntities data source into each remote connection string input. I also had a DefaultConnection string, do I need to add this one somewhere?:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;Initial Catalog=marsman57_;Integrated Security=False;User Id=stackoverflowid1;Password=stackoverflowpasswd1;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I tried following this tutorial, but it's a bit dated. Where am I going wrong, or what next steps do I need to take? Thank you!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure

**EDIT: PROGRESS FROM INITIAL QUESTION:**

Here's where I am at. I used SSMS and did `Tasks->Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database` this database now shows up in my SQL Server Object Explorer in visual studio with all the tables. I went to my Azure account and copied the ADO.NET connection string and pasted it in my `UnearthEntities` connection string as:

`<add name="UnearthEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.UnearthEntities.csdl‌​|res://*/Data.Uneart‌​hEntities.ssdl|res:/‌​/*/Data.UnearthEntit‌​ies.msl;provider=Sys‌​tem.Data.SqlClient;p‌​rovider connection string=&quot;data source=unearthappdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=marsman57_;integrated security=False;user id=unearthadmin;password=serverpasswd;MultipleActiveResultSe‌​ts=True;App=EntityFr‌​amework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Next, in my publish settings, I clicked the ellipses and selected the server I just imported:[image]

Upon publishing, I still retain the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

> An error occurred while processing your request.

You could disable the `customErrors` for retrieving more detailed error information to narrow this issue. And you could leverage [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) and navigate to `D:\home\site\wwwroot` and change your web.config file or redeploy your web application.

The web.config would look like this:

```html
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

> I tried following this tutorial, but it's a bit dated. Where am I going wrong, or what next steps do I need to take? Thank you!

Since you are using Database First, you need to publish your database to SQL Azure. In order to migrate your SQL Server database to Azure SQL Database, you could follow the approaches below:

- Use **SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)**, right click your database, then choose "Tasks > Export Data", configure the Data Source and Destination. More details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard#startSSMS).
- Use the **SSIS Import and Export Wizard** from Visual Studio, more details you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard#startVS).
- Use Data Migration Assistant, more details you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database).

**Note:** You need to set server firewall for your azure SQL Database and add the current IP address of your computer to access your Azure SQL Database.

After you migrated your database to SQL Azure, you could just update the connection string (`UnearthEntities`) under your web.config with the settings (data source, initial catalog, user id, password) from your SQL Azure or you could update your connection string when using the publish wizard under "Publish > Settings".

> I added the UnearthEntities data source into each remote connection string input. I also had a DefaultConnection string, do I need to add this one somewhere?

You need to update the connection string your are using with the related Entity Data Model.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! Here's where I am at. I used SSMS and did 'Tasks->Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database` this database now shows up in my SQL Server Object Explorer in visual studio with all the tables. I went to my Azure account and copied the ADO.NET connection string and pasted it in my `UnearthEntities` connection string as: check my initial question...ran out of space

Comment: The connection string `UnearthEntities` is used for database first, you need to keep the form and just update the server name, db name, username, password.

Comment: As you said, you have three connection strings. Which connection string are you using in your project ? The connection string `ApplicationDbContext` and `SongModelDbContext` are used for code first?

Comment: So I went back and simply modified the `UnearthEntities` hopefully this looks correct:  `<add name="UnearthEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.UnearthEntities.csdl|res://*/Data.UnearthEntities.ssdl|res://*/Data.UnearthEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=unearthappdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=marsman57_;integrated security=False;user id=unearthadmin;password=serverpasswd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: and in my web.config, I have DefaultConnection(ApplicationDbContext) and UnearthEntities as my connection strings. Hired a freelance to do the project, but was curious to see if I could personally deploy myself. So I'm trying to learn. How can I check if it's code first?

Comment: For code first, you need to define the data model, more details you could refer to this [tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#create-the-data-model). Also, you could refer to [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/entity-framework-code-first-vs-database-first-approach) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/code-first-vs-database-first-vs-model-first-approach1) about the differences between Code First, Database First, Model First.

Comment: Your `ApplicationDbContext` connection string may be a common connection string. For more details about the connection string examples, you could refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#Connection String Examples).

Comment: Ok so upon inspection, I think that UnearthEntities is database first since it has `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException()` in `onModelCreating` while the other two do not, so I assume those are code first

Comment: For code first approach, you could just copy the connection string from azure portal. Any concerns, feel free to let me know.